# Generalized Sequential Pattern algorithm MapReduce

Tags: java, python, mapreduce, gsp, graph-algorithm

I am looking for an example implementation of the Generalized Sequential Pattern algorithm (GSP) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSP_Algorithm

Whilst the Wikipedia article provides psuedo code, its a bit confusing and I would like to see some proper code (ideally python or java). Does anyone know a good reference?

I want to understand the algorithm first and then potentially make it work in a MapReduce world - which as the wikipedia article shows the use of counters I think could be complex.

I am doing this because I have a graph of events where the edges are constrained by time, a sequence would be where a node is connected to another node where A -> B happens between a start and a finish time and B -> C happens X time after B finishes in the first connection. A -> B -> C would be the sequence, a sequence can't revisit a node more than once.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some Java code for **GSP, PrefixSpan, SPADE, SPAM** and many others, check this website: http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/

Then you could check if you may adapt them into a map-reduce algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

SPMF is a good tool, which implements many algorithms.
It can help us to save a lot of time.
But we need to compare the performance on different algorithms such like Generalized Sequential Patterns (GSP), which is an important algorithm in sequential pattern mining.